# Kafka console tools Producer/Consumer test

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

After creating a "test" topic,

```
kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 4 --topic test
```

Which I see has been correctly created:

```
kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
Topic:test  PartitionCount:4    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: test Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: test Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: test Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: test Partition: 3    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

I have two console windows, a `Producer` and a `Consumer` console. The `Producer` comes up fine with:

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
>
```

When I try the following on the second console window:

```
kafka-console-consumer –bootstrap-server localhost:9092 –from-beginning –topic test
```

I get an error:

```
Exactly one of whitelist/topic is required.
Option                                   Description
------                                   -----------
--blacklist <String: blacklist>          Blacklist of topics to exclude from
                                           consumption.
...Lots more text here...
```

What is the correct way to listen for messages from a `Producer` in a console `Consumer`?

Comment: add '-'  to each option . kafka-console-consumer -–bootstrap-server localhost:9092 –-from-beginning –-topic test

Comment: Voting to close as typo. `--topic` has two hyphens, not the single long hyphen. Same for other options... Don't copy paste the text from online forms

Comment: Thanks that was the problem